# Gfx Card has DVI and HDMI, need to connect dual VGA

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, vga, dvi

A reasonable desktop of mine has an external gfx card with 1 DVI and 1 HDMI port. The motherboard itself has 1 VGA port. I have a VGA/DVI adapter for one monitor but if I hook up one to the gfx card and one to the mobo direct the BIOS tells me on startup to connect both to the card.

How can I do this and is it not possible to connect one to each?

Comment: The determination of if its possible depends on your hardware.  By the error it indicates, its not possible, with your hardware.

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to connect one to the MB and one to the GPU - but this could raise some issues. The VGA connector on your MB is actually for an integrated GPU either on your MB or on the CPU - if you have none you should not  even be able to use this one alone (eg. when using a GPU-less MB with a GPU-less serverprocessor).

When you would hook one monitor to each connector there could many problems arise as there would be the need of a solution to use both GPUs for different monitors but then: On which should the general computing be done (and not only the output)? This would be difficult to set up - probably similar to SLI or other dual-GPU setups but now even with different GPU vendors and models.

Technically it could be possible though.

Solution: Either buy a HDMI-to-VGA adapter or program a firmware or a driver for your setup ;-)

Comment: Or buy a second graphics card. Which might be cheaper than HDMI to VGA.

Comment: Given this is correct but how will you make this a cheaper solution? (I mean the second GPU need to be compatible with the other one and one needs to have enough space on the MB)

Comment: Would a second gfx card not have the same issue as I have now or do you mean in crossfire arrangement?

Comment: Aye. I keep forgetting about enough space on the motherboard (my boards tend to have plenty for things like extra NICs, RAID, Graphics etc). As to compatible: That should not be a problem since Vista. If you want you can even add things like AMD and Nvidia cards. XP and older only supported 1 graphics driver though, so yes. For old stuff they would need to be compatible.

Comment: No, not in crossfire. Crossfire DISABLES the outputs on on of the cards. (Or rather, it uses all crossfired cards for calculation only and only uses one cards output during crossfire mode.)

Comment: Yes, but you need to have GPus that support this (most modern do). Integrated mostly do not or only in a "strange" way like nVidia Optimus. Linux should not have a roblem with it too when the GPUs work. You *might* need to meddle with the Xorg.conf though

Comment: Aye. I lack experience with multiple GPUs on Linux and BSD's though. I only used this on windows.